# Changing IT policies in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is is possible to change the IT policies in blackberry by programing.....
And if it is possible then what are the policies can we change....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can not change IT policy from the device. If anyone is able to change IT policy, then what will be the purpose of it at first place. They can only be controlled by BES administrators.

Comment: Thanks......But i want some API's by which i can able to change some of the IT policies to enable or disable some functionality of the device...

Comment: As I said if an app is able to change IT policy using some API (which are of course not exposed), there is no point of having IT policy. IT policies are put in place to restrict device functionality.